# How do I upgrade without upgrading contributed modules?

Tags: 8, upgrading

I am trying to do a core upgrade, but my dry-run shows Drupal wants to install a number of modules that are already installed.

I run `composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-all-dependencies --dry-run` and I see these lines in the output.

> Installing drupal/smtp (1.1.0)
> Installing drupal/admin_toolbar (2.5.0)

How can I upgrade the core without upgrading contributed modules?  Why is Drupal trying to install modules that are already installed?

Comment: Why are you using `--with-all-dependencies`?

Comment: Do you also see complementary messages for each of these modules like _Locking drupal/smtp (1.1.0)_? If so it seems likely you have packages listed in composer.,json which aren't in composer.lock. When you run an update composer has to make sure that all packages are in sync, not just the ones you've requested for update in that specific command. If there are packages required in composer.json which haven't been properly installed (i.e. downloaded _and_ locked), composer will intervene. Drupal isn't relevant to this BTW, it would happen for any packages

Comment: @PatrickKenny  Because the documentation says to: https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer

Comment: @PatrickKenny Also, if I omit the --with-all-dependencies, it doesn't make any difference.  Composer still wants to install modules that are already installed.

Comment: @Clive  No, I don't see any messages that mention locking.

Comment: And these packages (drupal/smtp etc) are definitely already listed in composer.lock? Before you try the update?

Comment: @Clive  I am not sure.  But just now I removed the contributed modules from the "require" section of composer.json.  And then my core was upgraded successfully (without the module upgrades) when I ran "composer update" as part of this composer migration: https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/migrating-the-composer-project-for-drupal-earlier-than-880

Comment: @Clive  Seems like I shouldn't have to remove contributed modules from "required" to upgrade core alone, but that's what worked.

Comment: Simply showing us the composer.json file would prevent so much back-and-forth and for some reason not showing it is common here.

Comment: You absolutely do not need to remove anything from requirements before running composer update. That would be hacking around the problem, and the problem will just resurface next time. Your problem is that composer is under the impression it hasn’t installed these modules for you before. It doesn’t know about them being in your project yet. There are a few ways that can happen, all centred around composer.lock, so if you want to avoid this happening again, I’d recommend fixing the underlying problem and making composer aware of those modules

Comment: In fact what you did proved the point - if composer was aware of your modules, removing them from composer.json would have caused them to be removed completely when you ran `composer update`. So either you didn't install these modules with composer in the first place, or something has become corrupt since you did

Comment: did you try just `composer update drupal/core-recommended --dry-run` ?